# Matplotlib: How to fix unexpected x tick behaviour

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making matplotlib lineplots and the x ticks are behaving so counterintuitively.

Here is my dataframe:

```
    year        x       y
0   2012        8154    13496
1   2013        8585    11421
2   2014        10376   10890
3   2015        11720   10714
```

This code:

```
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12, 7))

ax1.plot(WholeGrouped['x'],
         marker='o',
         lw=1,
         markersize=9,
         linestyle = '--',
         color='#666666')

ax1.plot(WholeGrouped['y'],
         marker='o',
         lw=3,
         markersize=10,
         color='#12A4DD')

labels = [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]

ax1.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

Produces this:

[image]

Clearly though I want the year labels to be positioned relative to the markers. How do I assign the labels to the correct position?

The genesis of the problem is that Matplotlib returned something totally bizarre when I tried to use the years as the x axis. As follows:

```
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12, 7))

ax1.plot(WholeGrouped['x'],
         marker='o',
         lw=1,
         markersize=9,
         linestyle = '--',
         color='#666666')

ax1.plot(WholeGrouped['y'],
         WholeGrouped['year'],
         marker='o',
         lw=3,
         markersize=10,
         color='#12A4DD')
```

[image]

Hence I went down the labels route.

How hard can it be to make the x axis the years and have them properly spaced out!

Comment: You can reset the index of your dataframe to be the year. Then do a dataframe plot. That will give you the right graph.

Comment: In your second code example, you left out `WholeGrouped['year'],` when you plotted the `x` column. So the x's are plotted against the default (1,2,3,4) and the y's against the year values. Fix that and it will look a  lot better. Spinor's advice will work, too.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - neither works unfortunately. I really don't understand what's going on here. Reindexing the dataframe so they years are the index and calling `df.plot()` still doesn't set the years as x values. Also re your comment @cphlewis- it doesn't matter where I put `WholeGrouped['year']` - first, last, in both plots or just in one. Nothing sets the years as the x axis.

Comment: You should almost never use `set_ticklabels`, it de-couples the tick formatters from the data and hence can be very dangerous.

Comment: Also, the input to plot is `ax.plot(x, y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = [{'year':   2012, 'x':        8154   , 'y': 13496},
     {'year':   2013, 'x':        8585   , 'y': 11421},
     {'year':   2014, 'x':        10376  , 'y': 10890},
     {'year':   2015, 'x':        11720  , 'y': 10714},]

df_so = pd.DataFrame(d)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot('year', 'x', data=df_so)


ax.plot('year', 'y', data=df_so)

ax.xaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
ax.xaxis.get_major_locator().set_params(integer=True)
```

[image]

You need mpl 1.5+ for the data unpacking to work, otherwise use `df_so['x']` etc.  The styling here is a preview of the new 2.0 defaults